# DAG scheduler repeating the processing stages while using unionALL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We have two dataframes `df1` and `df2` and are performing transformations on df2. After all the transformations are done on df2 , we need to append the df1 in df2. For that, we are using the unionAll function .

```
val v_asciiFileWithHeader = v_header.unionAll(vr_dataframeAsciiFile)
```

But after `unionAll`, when we are printing its DAG , its repeating all the processing stages again due to which all the processing are done twice when an action is called.

If we are persisting the df2 before applying `unionAll`, then all  processing stages are not repeated.

For reference, have attached the DAG for the dataframe before `unionAll`, after `UnionAll(without persisting df2)`, after `unionAll(with persisting df2)`

So, why are processing stages repeating when `unionAll` is applied on unpersisted dataframe.

Spark-version - 1.6.1
Scala version - 2.10.6

[image: Print Schema for each dataframe]

Comment: Does processing part of 'df2' include any action or only transformations?

Comment: @code earlier it had only transformations . But for persist we have added a action i.e. df2.count

Comment: Earlier also df2 transformations were executed twice?

Comment: @code no if we are not using unionAll then its executing only once but when we using unionAll its executing twice. Same you see in the second image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark DAG scheduler separates your first set of transformations into one stage and union operation as another stage. Also, DAG schedule decides that these two stages can be run in parallel because they are not dependent on each other but on a common parent.

**So when it runs two stages in parallel, the same set of transformations will be run simultaneously.**

The solution to avoid this is to show that **these two stages are dependent on each other and should not be run in parallel**. So, when you call an action and persist the Dataframe before union operation, stage-1 will be executed first because it has an action at the end of it. Once that stage is completed, stage-2(i.e union action) is executed.

At this point, the dataframe required for union is already computed and persisted by stage-1 **so it will be used as it is instead of re-computing it**.

Hope this clarifies your doubt.

Comment: i wasn't able to get that even though we applied transformations to df2 , the same transformation were applied to the output of the df1.unionAll(df2)

Comment: Yes, that's because DAG schedule runs your transformation in one stage (stage-1) and union operation in another stage(stage-2). Now the DAG scheduler checks if the dataframes involved in stage-2 are computed or not. Since both the stages run parallelly, dataframes are not computed yet. So it calculates the dataframe being calculated in stage-1 again in stage-2.